# Why jQuery is not crossbrowser with Chrome for "css('left', '+=42')"?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

An exemple is better than long explain: http://jsfiddle.net/79a4eb37/
On firefox `css('left', '+=42')` works, on chrome no...

When left property is not iniialize, not works with chrome.

Comment: Yes, the offensive language is really required to show your frustration. Instead, you could try out couple of options to check what was going on.. I edited for you earlier.. but do you really need to edit it again.

Comment: chances are the default value in chrome differs from the default value in firefox in such a way that makes += not work.

Comment: Offensive language is irrelevant, the text at the bottom is similar to the common "Thank you!" text that generally gets removed from questions because they aren't relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Do you realy need to vote -1 for legitimate question :)

Comment: The question is legitimate, but you answered the question in the question. *"When left property is not iniialize, not works with chrome..."* solution is to initialize it.

Comment: @Matrix I didn't down vote your question, perhaps someone else did seeing that.. but then your question was super valid, but then why did you even post a question when you know the answer.. probably you should have self answered this question.. with a bug tracker in jQuery

Comment: Looks like you had to initialize `left: 0px` for chrome. See fiddle below http://jsfiddle.net/79a4eb37/1/

Comment: I don't have the solution, I want this instruction of code works and it's not, so if you have the code to modify in jQuery, I take.

Comment: we don't, sorry. Such code doesn't exist.

Comment: Someone inteligent can create it^^

Comment: See vega's comment and accompanying fiddle, he has created "code" that fixes this problem. Unfortunately it isn't the kind of code you seem to be requiring.

Comment: Fixing it in the core is going to be far more complex than simply setting a default css style.

Comment: Just for reference, the relevant part of jQuery core is here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L274

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it not works without initialization in Chrome is because it's designed this way. Take a look at [style function](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.style) of jQuery source:

```
    // convert relative number strings (+= or -=) to relative numbers. #7345
    if (type === "string" && (ret = rrelNum.exec(value))) {
        value = (ret[1] + 1) * ret[2] + parseFloat(jQuery.css(elem, name));
        // Fixes bug #9237
        type = "number";
    }

    // Make sure that NaN and null values aren't set. See: #7116
    if (value == null || type === "number" && isNaN(value)) {
        return;
    }
```

In Chrome part `parseFloat(jQuery.css(elem, name))` will return NaN for `left`, because `jQuery.css(elem, name)` on element without explicit `left` style will return `undefined`. Then function returns because calculated value is invalid.

However, in FF left will be 8px, according to my test. That's right, without initial `left:0` you'll get 108px offset in your fiddle (and I believe you're expecting 100px).

I suppose this is a main reason why code was writen like this − result will be different from browser to browser, and jQuery should not set up initial cross-browser values for you − it can break up **many** things. Use "explicit better than implicit" rule and just set `left` to 0.